# How to copy a CImage object?

Tags: c++, image, memory-management, copy, atl

I am trying to copy a `CImage` so that I can do some manipulation with it's pixels. I've tried this where `source` is a pointer to a loaded CImage object.

```
CImage* dest = new CImage(*source);
```

However this doesn't seem to work and I believe `source` and `dest` are pointing to the same memory.

How would I create a new copy totally detached from the previous CImage?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a question about MFC/ATL CImage then you can create new instance and use Create to initialize it to the size of the original CImage. Then use BitBlt to copy contents.

Comment: Yes it is ATL, can you explain how to use the `BitBlt`.

Comment: Here is a sample, srcImg.BitBlt(dstImg.GetDC(), 0, 0), dstImg should be compatible and of same size as srcImg.

Comment: Don't forget to call `dstImg.ReleaseDC()` to avoid leaks.